# The AudienceRestrictionCondition was not valid because the specified Audience is not present in AudienceUris

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing test application for ASP.NET MVC4 application in VS-2013 for single sign on with Azure active directory.
I am able to get login page but after login I m getting "The AudienceRestrictionCondition was not valid because the specified Audience is not present in AudienceUris Audience" Dot net error.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token) +996
       System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token) +73
       System.IdentityModel.Services.TokenReceiver.AuthenticateToken(SecurityToken token, Boolean ensureBearerToken, String endpointUri) +120
       System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase request) +493
       System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +364
       System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your test scenario, you've created a test application and you’re trying to authenticate using Azure active directory. If that’s the case, the error message you’re getting about “AudienceRestrictionCondition” and “AudienceUris” indicates that your test application’s config file is missing your site under the Audience Uris section or that the value is misspelled. It should look something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.identityModel>
        <identityConfiguration>
          <audienceUris>
            <add value="http://YourSiteHere/" />
          </audienceUris>
        </identityConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

Hope That Helps.

Comment: My earlier assumption was wrong. Does this value have to be in all small letters? Because I had a directory inside a website named "Web" but when I gave the value as "http://mySite/Web" it failed. When I changed the value to all small letters, it worked! So does it have to be in all small letters?

Comment: @AmoghNatu If you will post your comment as a question, and let me know, I will be happy to respond in greater detail. It can be difficult to fit a detailed answer in the character restrictions for a comment. 
Otherwise, the short answer would be: I am not aware of a case restriction on audienceUri values. However, the audienceUri value does need to match any corresponding values at other points in the configuration. Hope That Helps.

Comment: I understand. Sorry for that. I have posted the question here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27805093/2377928

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and when I changed the audience URL 
from `https://siteurl` to `https:siteurl/`.  i.e. add slash(`/`) it worked.